# How to get SecondOrDefault?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I have a simple linq lambda statement

```
Interactions = new BindableCollection<InteractionDTO>(ctx.Interactions.Where(x => x.ActivityDate > DateTime.Today)
   .Select(x => new InteractionDTO
   {
       Id = x.Id,
       ActivityDate = x.ActivityDate,
       subject = x.Subject,
       ClientNames = x.Attendees.Count == 1 ? x.Attendees.FirstOrDefault().Person.CorrespondenceName :
       x.Attendees.FirstOrDefault().Person.CorrespondenceName : "Multiple attendees"
    }));
```

This will give me the first Client Name, I'm trying to have it appear First 2 attendees followed by dots. I tried this

```
ClientNames = x.Attendees.Count == 1 ? 
             x.Attendees.FirstOrDefault().Person.CorrespondenceName :
             x.Attendees.FirstOrDefault().Person.CorrespondenceName +
             x.Attendees.Skip(1).FirstOrDefault().Person.CorrespondenceName + " ..."
```

But I get this error:

> The method 'Skip' is only supported for sorted input in LINQ to Entities. The method 'OrderBy' must be called before the method 'Skip'.

Comment: Perhaps replace Skip(1) with Take(2)?

Comment: ^ worked like a charm @GrantWinney Thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could try ordering first, as the message suggests.

I'm not sure what your `Attendees` class looks like, but assuming it has an ID field:

```
x.Attendees.OrderBy(a => a.ID)
           .Skip(1)
           .Select(a => a.Person.CorrespondenceName).FirstOrDefault() + " ..."
```

---

*A couple other notes:*

I swapped your `Select` and `FirstOrDefault` statements. The way you've currently got it, if `FirstOrDefault()` returns null, then `Person.CorrespondenceName` will throw an exception.

But now if no record is found, you'll end up with just `"..."`. You might want to adjust your first `Where` clause to filter out records that have no correspondance name, and then change `FirstOrDefault()` to `First()`.

---

EDIT:

That should steer you in the right direction *(I hope)*. This may be more what you're looking for, assuming it can actually be translated into a valid SQL statement:

```
ClientNames = x.Attendees.Any()
                  ? x.Attendees.Count == 1
                      ? x.Attendees.Select(a => a.Person.CorrespondenceName).FirstOrDefault()
                      : x.Attendees.Count == 2
                          ? string.Join(", ", x.Attendees.OrderBy(a => a.ID).Take(2)
                                                         .Select(a => a.Person.CorrespondenceName).FirstOrDefault()
                          : string.Join(", ", x.Attendees.OrderBy(a => a.ID).Take(2)
                                                         .Select(a => a.Person.CorrespondenceName).FirstOrDefault() + " ..."
                  : "No client name available";
```

Comment: You need a Skip(1) in there to get the second or default desired.

Answer (score 1):

```
// put this in your namespace...

public static class EnumerableExtension
{ 
    public static TSource SecondOrDefault<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source)
    {
        var iterator = source.GetEnumerator();
        if (iterator.MoveNext() && iterator.MoveNext() )            
            return iterator.Current;            
        else 
            return default( TSource );
    }
}

// Usage... var thing = list.SecondOrDefault();
```