# Get next value after FirstOrDefault

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, asp.net-core

I have mapping for field PreviousDueDate

Here is it

```
ForMember(x => x.LastExtendedDate,
            opt =>
            {
                opt.PreCondition(aa => aa.CompanySurveyDueDates is {Count: > 0});
                opt.MapFrom(aa =>
                    aa.CompanySurveyDueDates.Where(x => x.IsInitial == false).OrderByDescending(x => x.Id)
                        .FirstOrDefault().DueDate);
            })
```

Here is I get first value with `Initial == false`

But I need to get next value of `FirstOrDefault`

How I can do it?

Comment: What about `Skip(1)`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23573803/how-to-get-secondordefault

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.Skip(1)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.skip?view=net-6.0) before `.FirstOrDefault()` to skip the first record from the sequence.

> Bypasses a specified number of elements in a sequence and then returns
> the remaining elements.

```
ForMember(x => x.LastExtendedDate,
   opt =>
   {
       opt.PreCondition(aa => aa.CompanySurveyDueDates is {Count: > 0});
       opt.MapFrom(aa =>
             aa.CompanySurveyDueDates
                 .Where(x => x.IsInitial == false)
                 .OrderByDescending(x => x.Id)
                 .Skip(1) //This will skip the first record
                 .FirstOrDefault().DueDate);
   })
```